# Not able to generate inference for propertyChainAxiom

Tags: ontology, graphdb

I am using propertyChainAxiom to build one of the inference statements. I have defined a basic ontology which defines properties and statements as below :

ex:

```
:isParent rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
:Person1 :hasParent :Person2.
:Person2 :hasParent :Person3.

:hasGrandParent owl:propertyChainAxiom (:hasParent :hasParent) . 

:Person1 :hasGrandParent ?o .
```

I have defined ontology and thesaurus in Ontotext GraphDB and have used the OWL2-horst ruleset. 
The statement :Person1 :hasGrandParent doesn't seems to return Person3 as per inferred statement. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Are you able to confirm this with any other reasoning system? I am able to get the desired inference using Protege+HermiT. However, it was necessary for to me to add explicit declarations (adding rdf:types to owl:Individual and owl:ObjectProperty). It may be the case the GraphDB rule implementation requires the same.

Comment: There is no support of property chain axioms in `owl-horst` ruleset. You should setup your repository to use `owl2-rl` instead.

Comment: I verified the ruleset of owl-horst it doesnt have property chain axiom. Moving to owl2-rl worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273427/how-can-i-go-straight-to-the-source-of-a-node-from-the-visual-graphAnswered (so it doesn't appear in `[graphdb] answers:0` again)

Answer (score 0):

As Damyan said, use OWL-RL.

Reposting his comment as answer, so this question doesn't appear again in `[graphdb] answers:0`

Comment: Copying a comment into an answer is OK, if you follow the [referencing requirements](/help/referencing), which require that you give attribution. The actual requirements of the CC BY-SA license are a bit more stringent as to what qualifies as attribution. Do not include notes such as ", so this question doesn't appear again in `[graphdb] answers:0`", as they have nothing to do with the actual answer. When the *only* thing you are doing is copying a comment into an answer, it's common to make your answer a community wiki.

Comment: In this case, the actual comment is significantly more informative than your answer. In this case, it would be better to just actually quote the comment, or at least give equivalent information.

Comment: I mentioned Damyan's name, how is that not giving attribution? BTW he is my colleague at Ontotext.